# Как проверить спарсился ли последний txt.фаил?

Tags: android

Ребята, помогите разобраться. Я новичек в программировании.Делаю приложение тест.
Есть первая activity,в ней  кнопка-меню, нажимаешь и переходишь во вторую activity,
где выводятся вопросы с вариантами ответов. Весь контент я беру из
txt- файлов,которые лежат в папке assets.Сейчас их 7. По одному на каждый вопрос.

Файлы имеют такие названия: z1v1.txt - задание один вопрос один, второй z1v2 и т.д.

```
String parsing_txt = "z1v" + actualq + ".txt";
```

Переменная actualq - актуальный вопрос по нажатию на radiobutton увеличивается на 1 и
таким образом происходит парсинг и вопросы меняются.

Когда спарсиваю последний вопрос, то выкидывает в 1 activity. Вопрос:Почему?
И второй: как написать проверку,типа спарсился последний TXT - вывод результатов.

Намучилась я, ничего не выходит. Я уже и у увеличивала до 7 actualq, типа на седьмом нажатии выводи мне мой метод подсчета результатов (7 потому, что первый вопрос выводится в onCreate)

```
if (actualq==7){

        displayResult();
}
```

Все бестолку. Выкидывает в activity с менюшной кнопкой и хоть ты тресни.

Вот код:

```
public class MainActivityTwo extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button next, resalt;
TextView question;
TextView right_or_wrong;
int total = 7;// сколько всего вопросов в тесте
int right_option = 0; // правильные ответы
int actualq = 1;// номер текущего вопроса
int actuala = 0;// номер текущего otveta (1-pervaja knopka, 2-vtoraja knopka, 3-tretja knopka)


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_two);


    resalt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resalt);
    resalt.setOnClickListener(this);

    question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    right_or_wrong = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    String parsing_txt = "z1v1.txt";//
    String s1 = LoadTXT.TXT(this, parsing_txt);// записываем содержимое файла в переменную типа string
    StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(s1, "*");// делим строку по критерию *
    question.setText(st1.nextToken());
    st1.nextToken();
    String actuala1 = st1.nextToken();// записываем ответы

    actuala = Integer.parseInt(actuala1);// ответы из string в примитивный тип int

    st1.nextToken();
    String Are = st1.nextToken();
    st1.nextToken();
    String Is = st1.nextToken();
    st1.nextToken();
    String Am = st1.nextToken();

    RadioButton option1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.variant1);// находим radiobutton по id
    option1.setText(Are);// выводим 1 вариант ответа.
    RadioButton option2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.variant2);// находим radiobutton по id
    option2.setText(Is);// выводим 2 вариант ответа.

    RadioButton option3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.variant3);// находим radiobutton по id
    option3.setText(Am);// выводим 3 вариант ответа.


}// end method onCreate


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    RadioGroup myRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_group);
    int index = myRadioGroup.indexOfChild(findViewById(myRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()));


    /*if (actualq==7){

        displayResult();
    }*/

    if (index == -1) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Вы ничего не выбрали", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }// проверка нажал ли юзер вообще на radiobutton */


    if (index == 0) { /*1 knopka*/
        if (actuala == 1) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "pravilny otvet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
            right_option++;
            actualq++;

        } else {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "ne pravilny otvet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
            actualq++;

        }
    }
    if (index == 1) { /*2 knopka*/
        if (actuala == 2) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "pravilny otvet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
            right_option++;
            actualq++;

        } else {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "ne pravilny otvet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
            actualq++;

        }
    }
    if (index == 2) { /*2 knopka*/
        if (actuala == 3) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "pravilny otvet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
            right_option++;
            actualq++;

        } else {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "ne pravilny otvet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
            actualq++;

        }
    }

    String parsing_txt = "z1v" + actualq + ".txt";// z1v1

    String s1 = LoadTXT.TXT(this, parsing_txt);// записываем содержимое файла в переменную типа string
    StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(s1, "*");
    question.setText(st1.nextToken());// выводим вопросы теста
    st1.nextToken();
    String actuala1 = st1.nextToken();// записываем правильные ответы в string переменную
    actuala = Integer.parseInt(actuala1);// ответы из string в  тип int
    st1.nextToken();
    String Are = st1.nextToken();// radiobutton
    st1.nextToken();
    String Is = st1.nextToken();// radiobutton
    st1.nextToken();
    String Am = st1.nextToken();// radiobutton

    RadioButton option1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.variant1);// находим radiobutton по id
    option1.setText(Are);// выводим 1 вариант ответа.
    RadioButton option2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.variant2);// находим radiobutton по id
    option2.setText(Is);// выводим 2 вариант ответа.

    RadioButton option3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.variant3);// находим radiobutton по id
    option3.setText(Am);// выводим 3 вариант ответа.

    myRadioGroup.clearCheck();// снимаем метку



}// end method onClick


void displayResult() {// выводить результаты я буду как-то так

    TextView resultTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    resultTV.setText("Тест завершён! Правильно: " + right_option + " из " + total + ".");



}

}// end class MainActivityTwo
```

Comment: А какую ошибку дает? в дебаггере посмотрите

Comment: Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-21 10:33:58.948 1484-1866/system_process I/ActivityManager: Process ua.homework2 (pid 5274) has died.

Comment: все понятно. Вам нужно создать отделный поток (AsyncTaskом к примеру) и потом загрузку из файла передать туда. Вот тогда все будет работать. У вас основной поток долго держится

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте что то типо такого

```
public class MainActivityTwo extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button next, resalt;
    TextView question;
    TextView right_or_wrong;
    int total = 7;// сколько всего вопросов в тесте
    int right_option = 0; // правильные ответы
    int actualq = 1;// номер текущего вопроса
    int actuala = 0;// номер текущего otveta (1-pervaja knopka, 2-vtoraja knopka, 3-tretja knopka)
    ReadFromMyFile readFromMyFile = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_two);

        resalt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resalt);
        resalt.setOnClickListener(this);

        question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        right_or_wrong = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        if (readFromMyFile != null) {
            readFromMyFile = new ReadFromMyFile();
            readFromMyFile.execute();
        }

    }// end method onCreate

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        RadioGroup myRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_group);
        int index = myRadioGroup.indexOfChild(findViewById(myRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()));

        switch (index) {
            case 0: /* 1 knopka */
            case 1: /* 2 knopka */
            case 2: /* 3 knopka */
                Toast toast;
                if (actuala == index + 1) {
                    toast = Toast.makeText(this, "pravilny otvet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    right_option++;
                } else {
                    toast = Toast.makeText(this, "ne pravilny otvet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                }
                actualq++;
                toast.show();
            default:
                toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Вы ничего не выбрали", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
                // проверка нажал ли юзер вообще на radiobutton */
                break;
        }

        if (readFromMyFile != null) { // запускаем отдельный поток
            readFromMyFile = new ReadFromMyFile();
            readFromMyFile.execute();
        }
    }// end method onClick

    void displayResult() {// выводить результаты я буду как-то так
        TextView resultTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        resultTV.setText("Тест завершён! Правильно: " + right_option + " из " + total + ".");
    }

    void setViews() {
        RadioButton option1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.variant1);// находим radiobutton по id
        option1.setText(Are);// выводим 1 вариант ответа.
        RadioButton option2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.variant2);// находим radiobutton по id
        option2.setText(Is);// выводим 2 вариант ответа.

        RadioButton option3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.variant3);// находим radiobutton по id
        option3.setText(Am);// выводим 3 вариант ответа.

        myRadioGroup.clearCheck();// снимаем метку

        readFromMyFile = null;
    }

    class ReadFromMyFile extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        MainActivity activity;

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            setViews();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String parsing_txt = "z1v" + actualq + ".txt";// z1v1
            String s1 = LoadTXT.TXT(this, parsing_txt);// записываем содержимое файла в переменную типа string
            StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(s1, "*");
            question.setText(st1.nextToken());// выводим вопросы теста
            st1.nextToken();
            String actuala1 = st1.nextToken();// записываем правильные ответы в string переменную
            actuala = Integer.parseInt(actuala1);// ответы из string в  тип int
            st1.nextToken();
            String Are = st1.nextToken();// radiobutton
            st1.nextToken();
            String Is = st1.nextToken();// radiobutton
            st1.nextToken();
            String Am = st1.nextToken();// radiobutton
        }
    }
}

}// end class MainActivityTwo
```

Comment: Спасибо, жаль моя  маленькая репутация  не позволяет правильно Вас отблагодарить.

Comment: @Anna_True_sheva все нормально. У вас за 2 дня появится галочка, для `лучший ответ` и вот тогда будет ваша благодарность ))) Спасибо !